# What is the difference between Greedy-Search and Uniform-Cost-Search?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, greedy

When searching in a tree, my understanding of uniform cost search is that for a given node A, having child nodes B,C,D with associated costs of (10, 5, 7), my algorithm will choose C, as it has a lower cost. After expanding C, I see nodes E, F, G with costs of (40, 50, 60). It will choose 40, as it has the minimum value from both 3.

Now, isn't it just the same as doing a Greedy-Search, where you always choose what seems to be the best action?

Also, when defining costs from going from certain nodes to others, should we consider the whole cost from the beginning of the tree to the current node, or just the cost itself from going from node n to node n'?

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Nope. Your understanding isn't quite right.

The next node to be visited in case of uniform-cost-search would be D, as that has the lowest total cost from the root (7, as opposed to 40+5=45).

Greedy Search doesn't go back up the tree - it picks the lowest value and commits to that. Uniform-Cost will pick the lowest total cost from the entire tree.

Answer (score 9):

In a uniform cost search you always consider all unvisited nodes you have seen so far, not just those that are connected to the node you looked at. So in your example, after choosing C, you would find that visiting G has a total cost of 40 + 5 = 45 which is higher than the cost of starting again from the root and visiting D, which has cost 7. So you would visit D next.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between them is that the Greedy picks the node with the lowest heuristic value while the UCS picks the node with the lowest action cost. Consider the following graph:

[image]

If you run both algorithms, you'll get:

- UCS

Picks: S (cost 0), B (cost 1), A (cost 2), D (cost 3), C (cost 5), G (cost 7)

Answer: S->A->D->G

- Greedy:

*supposing it chooses the A instead of B; A and B have the same heuristic value

Picks: S , A (h = 3), C (h = 1), G (h = 0)

Answer: S->A->C->G

So, it's important to differentiate the action cost to get to the node from the heuristic value, which is a piece of information that is added to the node, based on the understanding of the problem definition.

Comment: The image in your answer is reported as broken. Can you please upload a new image? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Greedy search (for most of this answer, think of greedy best-first search when I say greedy search) is an **informed** search algorithm, which means the function that is evaluated to choose which node to expand has the form of f(n) = h(n), where h is the heuristic function for a given node n that returns the estimated value **from this node n to a goal state**. If you're trying to travel to a place, one example of a heuristic function is one that returns the estimated distance **from node n to your destination**.

Uniform-cost search, on the other hand, is an **uninformed** search algorithm, also known as a blind search strategy. This means that the value of the function f for a given node n, f(n), for uninformed search algorithms, takes into consideration g(n), the total action cost **from the root node to the node n**, that is, the path cost. It doesn't have any information about the problem apart from the problem description, so that's all it can know. You don't have any information that can help you decide how close one node is to a goal state, only to the root node. You can watch the nodes expanding [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyoucHYKYSE) (Animation of the Uniform Cost Algorithm) and see how the cost from node n to the root is used to choose which nodes to expand.

Greedy search, just like any greedy algorithm, takes locally optimal solutions and uses a function that returns an estimated value from a given node n to the goal state. You can watch the nodes expanding [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv1m3L6QXWs) (Greedy Best First Search | Quick Explanation with Visualization) and see how the return of the heuristic function from node n to the goal state is used to choose which nodes to expand.

By the way, sometimes, the path chosen by greedy search is not a global optimum. In the example in the video, for example, node A is never expanded because there are always nodes with smaller values of h(n). But what if A has such a high value, and the values for the next nodes are very small and therefore a global optimum? That can happen. A bad heuristic function can cause this. Getting stuck in a loop is also possible. A*, which is also a greedy search algorithm, fixes this by making use of both the path cost (which implies knowing nodes already visited) and a heuristic function, that is, f(n) = g(n) + h(n).

It's possible that to this point, it's still not clear to you HOW uniform-cost knows there is another path that looks better locally but not globally. It should become clear after telling you that if all paths have the same cost, uniform cost search is the same thing as the breadth-first search (BFS). It would expand all nodes just like BFS.

Answer (score 0):

UCS cares about history,
Greedy does not.
In your example, after expanding C, the next node would be D according to the UCS. Because, it's our history. UCS can't forget the past and remember that the total cost of D is much lower than E.

Don't be Greedy. Be UCS and if going back is really a better choice, don't afraid of going back!